# Not all records are being fetched by firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I use grade field in my queries, all my queries are not working, kindly help.

```
      result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .where("grade", isEqualTo: 10)
          .limit(3)
          .get();
```

User with grades are below
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

But the result fetched is just 1 As can be seen in debugging.
[image]

Comment: Hmmm... from the code and data you shared it seems like you indeed should be getting more documents back, so the problem is probably somewhere we can't see.  If nobody else spots it either, it might be helpful if you could set up a repro on a tool like zapp.run - so that we can see what happens there.

Comment: It was working fine after I created just a repo.And now I resolved it somehow but don't know how.